# Can't change line's color in matplotlib with rcParams

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I need a red line, but the following code part doesn't work:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc("lines", marker="x", linewidth=5, color="r")
import pylab
pylab.plot([1,2,3])
pylab.show()
```

[image: Line is not red.]

`marker` and `linewidth` changed, but not `color`.

**Used environment:**

- Operation system: Windows
- IDE: PyCharm.
- Python version: Python3.5 with Anaconda3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really how `matplotlib.rc` should be used. It's more global configuration. I also don't think `color` alone is a valid parameter.

For just a single plot, do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], linestyle='-', color='r', linewidth=2)
fig.savefig('plot_with_red_line.png', dpi=100)
```

Also, don't use the pylab interface. Use pyplot.

Comment: Why do you say that's not how `rc` should be used? This is actually how it's used [in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings). And notably, the example there doesn't change the color either.

Answer (score 1):

By default, colors are specified by a [Cycler](https://matplotlib.org/cycler/generated/cycler.Cycler.html#cycler.Cycler) object. Manually specifying a color in the `pyplot.plot()` (or `axes.Axes.plot()`) command (see [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34650885/7232335)) will change the color *for a single plot*. If you want to change the default color **for all line plots**, read on.

I'll start with an example derived from [the matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-matplotlib-with-style-sheets-and-rcparams):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

plt.ion()  # Interactive mode on.
data = np.random.randn(50)

# Want to change default line color to cyan.
mpl.rc('lines', linewidth=4, color='c')

# Plot; linewidth changes, color doesn't.
plt.plot(data)
```

[image: Color is still <code>'tab:blue'</code>, not cyan.]

The color didn't change to cyan as desired.

Now, I noticed the following line at the [bottom of the page](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#a-sample-matplotlibrc-file) in the sample matplotlibrc file:

> `#lines.color       : C0      ## has no affect on plot(); see axes.prop_cycle`

It turns out that in order to cycle through colors in default matplotlib plots, a Cycler is assigned to `axes.Axes` objects. We need to [provide a different cycler](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html#styling-with-cycler) with the `color` property we want. Continuing from the previous example...

```
plt.close()

from cycler import cycler

custom_cycler = (cycler(color=['c', 'm', 'y', 'k']) + cycler(linewidth=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
mpl.rc('axes', prop_cycle=custom_cycler)

for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(data + i)
```

[image: Cycler has changed axes properties.]

Woohoo! We changed the default color cycle as desired and learned about [Cyclers](https://matplotlib.org/cycler/generated/cycler.Cycler.html#cycler.Cycler) in the process, which can cycle through other properties like `linewidth` too. Of course, if you want all plots to be of one color, just provide a list containing a single value to the Cycler.

---

**NOTE:** It's also possible to change the property cycler for an `axes.Axes` instance via [`axes.Axes.set_prop_cycle()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_prop_cycle.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_prop_cycle).

**NOTE 2:** [As Paul said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34650885/7232335), don't use pylab; use pyplot. [pylab is deprecated](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related).